# C language recursion control

Tags: c

The program is about the function recursion, need to know how the control to the entire program

```
void count(int n)
{
  static int d=1;
  printf("%d",n);
  printf("%d",d);
  d++;
  if(n>1)
    count(n-1);
  printf("%d",d);
}

void main()
{
  count(3);
}
```

My expected output is

```
3122134
```

Original output is

```
312213444
```

Can anyone please explain how those extra two 4's has added to output?

Please explain about flow control about this program.

Comment: whether the function goes back after checking count(1) to print count(2) and count(3)

Comment: Use a debugger and step through the code line by line, and step into the recursive calls.

Comment: @mvs  The function calls itself when n is equal to 3, 2,, and 1 and for each call it outputs d in the last statement. So you get 444 at the tail of the output.

Comment: ya thats what I am asking when n equals to 1, the condition goes false and the printf() statement gets executed once and there the function will terminate or goes back and prints d value when n is 2 and 3 @VladfromMoscow

Comment: For me using these n as count(12344556) it is an abomination because it use too much stack space ( if it is not compiled in code that is iterative )

Comment: Each pass though the function prints 3 times - no exceptions.  In this case, always one digit.  The function is called 3 times.  So why expect 7 (a non-multiple of 3) digits to be printed?

Answer (score 3):

Here you're a friendly drawing to help you understand why this happens (the `static` is not a problem because you update the variable `static int d`, doing `d++` inside the function):
[image]

When you call recursion inside the function, `count(2)` starts, but `count(3)` is not destroyed, it is only sleeping, waiting for the subfunction `count(2)` to finish. When this happens, `count(3)` wakes up and says "Oh, finally! My daughter `count(2)` has finished, so it's my turn now to finish". But remember that, inside `count(2)`, you call `count(1)`...

Comment: Nice drawing!  Very easy to understand.